# enfileirar itens em uma fila (ponteiros)

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados

Olá, eu estou implementando uma função de inserir elementos em uma fila
e percebi que depois do primeiro elemento inserido, o ponteiro `headPtr` e ´tailPtr`estão apontando para o mesmo lugar, logo o problema só pode estar na função`enfileira`, porém eu não consigo soluciona-lo.
Alguém poderia me apontar o erro dela ? Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct node {
  int elemento;
  struct node* prox;
}FILA;

int ehvazia(FILA* p) {
  return p == NULL;
}

void verifica(FILA* p) {

    if(ehvazia(p)) {
        printf("MEMORIA INDISPONIVEL\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void espia(FILA* headPtr) {
    printf("%d\n", headPtr->elemento);
}

void enfileira(FILA* headPtr, FILA* tailPtr) {

    FILA* temp = malloc(sizeof(FILA));
    verifica(temp);

    int valor;
    printf("Valor: ");
    scanf("%d", &valor);

    temp->elemento = valor;

    if(ehvazia(headPtr)) {
        headPtr = temp;
        tailPtr = head;
    } else {
        tailPtr->prox = temp;
        tailPtr = temp;
    }

}

void desinfileira(FILA* headPtr, FILA* tailPtr) {

    FILA* tempPtr;

    tempPtr = headPtr;
    headPtr = headPtr->prox;

    if(ehvazia(headPtr)) {
        tailPtr = NULL;
    }

    free(tempPtr);

};



void imprimefila(FILA* headPtr, FILA* tailPtr) {

    FILA* atual;
    atual = headPtr;

    printf("A fila eh: \n");
    while(atual != NULL) {
        printf("-->%d", atual->elemento);
        atual = atual->prox;
    }

    //printf("A fila está vazia\n");


}

int main() {

    FILA* inicio = NULL;
    FILA* fim = NULL;

    int res;

    do {

        printf("DESEJA INSERIR MAIS? <1>S <0>N\n");
        scanf("%d", &res);

        if(res == 1){

            enfileira(inicio, fim);

        }

    }while(res <=  1 && res > 0);

    imprimefila(inicio, fim);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O primeiro erro aparece em:

```
tailPtr = head;
```

Dentro da função enfileira porque `head` não existe, tem de ser `headPtr` ou `temp`. Depois no fim da função `desinfileira` tem:

```
}tailPtr = temp;
```

Que também não pode estar pois fora da função o `node` `temp` não existe uma vez que foi criado dentro da função. Com isto desaparecem os erros de compilação no entanto existe outro pormenor relevante que não deixa o código funcionar corretamente.

Dentro da função `enfileira` recebe o ponteiro para a `FILA`, mas este é uma copia do ponteiro que está no main, logo uma instrução deste genero:

```
void enfileira(FILA* headPtr, FILA* tailPtr) {
   ...
   headPtr = temp;
```

Não tem o efeito desejado pois não altera o ponteiro do main. Uma solução comum para este problema é retornar o novo valor para o ponteiro, mas como temos dois ponteiros também não funciona. Em vez disso podemos passar um ponteiro para o ponteiro que temos no main, chamando a função assim:

```
int main() {
    ...
    if(res == 1){ 
        enfileira(&inicio, &fim); //passa agora o endereço do ponteiro
    }
```

E agora na função `enfileira` temos que ajustar o código para esta diferença:

```
void enfileira(FILA** headPtr, FILA** tailPtr) {

    FILA* temp = malloc(sizeof(FILA));
    verifica(temp);

    int valor;
    printf("Valor: ");
    scanf("%d", &valor);

    temp->elemento = valor;
    temp->prox = NULL;

    if(ehvazia(*headPtr)) { //alterada
        *headPtr = temp; //alterada
        *tailPtr = temp; //alterada
    } else {
        (*tailPtr)->prox = temp; //alterada
        *tailPtr = temp; //alterada
    }

}
```

Falta agora aplicar o mesmo principio a função `desinfileira`, e deixo esse desafio para si.

Comment: Isac. Muito obrigado, eu alterei o código aqui, funcionou perfeitamente.  Porém eu fiz um lista simplesmente encadeada utilizando ponteiros, inclusive tirei uma dúvida aqui no fórum, e não utilizei passagem por referência para resolver o problema, e funcionou também. Então, por que no meu código eu devo usar a passagem por referência ?

Comment: Porque tem os ponteiros no main, que eu assumi que queria. Outra solução é colocar os objetos no main em vez de ponteiros, e a função recebendo os ponteiros já funciona. Mas com ponteiro normal no main e ponteiro normal no `enfileira` não funciona.